# TestNG failing to recognize skipped Tests

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider, testng.xml

I use ITestListener in my tests and use `throw new SkipException` to skip my tests. After upgrading TestNG to 7.x I started seeing that my skipped tests are ignored when it's generating report at suite level.

When I execute my tests, this is the result I see at class level

```
 passed=7
 failed=0
 skipped=3
```

and at the suite level

```
 passed=7
 failed=0
 skipped=0
```

Here's my TestNG xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name=“TestSuite" verbose="2">
    <test name=“MyTests">
        <classes>
            <class name=“MyTestClass”>
                <methods>
                    <include name="testMethod”></include>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

TestListener class

```
public class MyTestListener implements ITestListener {

@Override
public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
    List<ITestResult> resultsList = new LinkedList<>();
    context.setAttribute(myTest, resultsList);
}

@Override
public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
    IResultMap passedTests = context.getPassedTests();
    IResultMap failedTests = context.getFailedTests();
    IResultMap skippedTests = context.getSkippedTests();
    Logger.print("passed=" + passedTests.size(), "failed=" + failedTests.size(), "skipped=" + skippedTests.size());
}

@Override
public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
}

@Override
public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
}

@Override
public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
    String name = getName(result);
    recordTestResult(name, "PASS");
    saveToContext(result);
}

@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    String name = getName(result);
    recordTestResult(name, "FAIL");
    saveToContext(result);
}

@Override
public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
    String name = getName(result);
    recordTestResult(name, "SKIP");
    saveToContext(result);
}
```

I added ISuiteListener to see if I can override the result but I don't have my skipped tests when I try to retrieve skipped count

```
public class MySuiteListener implements ISuiteListener {
    @Override
    public void onStart(ISuite suite) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {
        Map<String, ISuiteResult> results = suite.getResults();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ISuiteResult> result : results.entrySet()) {
            ISuiteResult suiteResult = result.getValue();
            ITestContext suiteContext suiteResult.getTestContext();
            IResultMap passedTests = suiteContext.getPassedTests();
            IResultMap failedTests = suiteContext.getFailedTests();
            IResultMap skippedTests suiteContext.getSkippedTests();
```

from ISuiteListener class.

Comment: Verify if onTestSkipped() is called during the tests.
Also try changing the verbose to10,

Comment: Verified onTestSkipped() is called. Changed verbose to 10, still the same result. I'm thinking since I'm able to get correct result for number of passedTests and failedTests and always I run the tests for a fixed count. Is there any way that I can override the testNG report.xml similar to skippedCount = (number of tests -(passedCount+failedCount)).